# JavaScript. Dictionary Key is not a String?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, key

Just a simple question. Having the next piece of code:

```
  function addMarker(data) {
    var types = {'meet': 380 + ',' + 95, 'vegetable': 285 + ',' + 0};
    var selection = data.type;

    console.log(types["meet"]);
    console.log(types[selection]);
    console.log(selection);
```

and having these results in the console:

```
380,95
undefined
Meet
```

I'd need to have in the second case also a 380,95. `selection` is supposed to be a string coming from the `data` object. Somehow when using this string like a dictionary key it's not working. How could I do then to get different values from `types` in some dynamic way like this?

Just to clarify, I'm not trying to get float numbers, what I need are two numbers separated by a `,`

Comment: Hops! You are right, thank you for the help. I didn't take the attention on the capital M, sorry to bother you with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is **case sensitive**. Object has property `meet` whereas value of **Selection** is `Meet`. Hence, you will need to update your code to following

```
console.log(types[selection.toLowerCase()]);
```

For reference, [String.toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)

Answer (score 0):

Please check if

```js
data.type === "Meet" // true
```

It should be "meet".

Btw. it is spelled meat, not meet.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear

```
addMarker({'type':'meet'}) // would produce correct result 
addMarker({'type':'Meet'}) // would produce result  result you see
```

To correct this you could use lower Case String ,as provided by Nikhil

```
 function addMarker(data) {
        var types = {'meet': 380 + ',' + 95, 'vegetable': 285 + ',' + 0};
        var selection = data.type;
       selection = selection.toLowerCase();

        console.log(types["meet"]);
        console.log(types[selection]);
        console.log(selection);
}
```

Or simply make proper call